# Realm is not displaying values in my UILabel

Tags: swift, realm

Here's my code:

```
 var selectedRoom = try! Realm().objects(Room.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "name")
```

In `override func viewDidLoad()`, I have

```
 roomMeasurementLabel.text = "\(selectedRoom)!"
 measurementSummaryNameLabel.text = "\(selectedRoom)!"
 countertopRoomLabel.text = "\(selectedRoom)!"
```

The results in `roomMeasurementLabel` are as it would be expected ie. 'Kitchen'.

The results in `measurementSummaryNameLabel` and `countertopRoomLabel` however, are 'Results(then the model name Room between less than and greater than brackets)'

All of the labels are in their own `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 3):

Realm.objects returns a Results< Room >, which is a collection of objects and not a single object as your variable name suggests.  If you want the first object its selectedRoom.first and this is an optional since Results could have 0 elements.

Comment: It turns out that there was an error in another part of my code that was the problem.  I had two outlets to the same label which meant it was getting it's text set from two sources.  Your answer helped me find it.  Thanks.